# Convert date in query function and order by date column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a large set of data that's updated every 2 weeks, so I'm looking to simplify the solution.

Imported sheet has data from D6:G. The **date** is in Column B.

Right now, I insert column H and use
`=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(B6:B),"",datevalue(B6:B)))`

In a new sheet, I import the data and order by Col H (the converted date) and Col G (the employee's name).
`=query(TimeApr10!B6:H,"select B,C,D,E,F,G where H is not null order by H,G asc")`

Is there a way to combine the two steps by converting Col B in the query to datevalue? If I don't convert the date, the ordering doesn't work.

Comment: This might sound very simple, but have you tried to format the `B` column as a date? If you did and still didn't work please share  a sample spreadsheet so I can see how your data is set up.

Comment: LOL, that worked. I know it's a simple step to select the column, but I'm trying to automate everything and pass it along to a colleague. Is there any way to do the conversion in the query? A new tab of data is uploaded every 2 weeks. Ideally, I wouldn't have to change Col B each time. Someone could easily forget this step.

Comment: How is your data laid out, maybe it's easier to have an Apps Script (or modify the current one) to format your column as date? Are you used to Apps Script? If not I don't know an easy straightforward way of doing this.